# why Android Studio doesn't recognize CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to make collapsing Toolbar, at first i add

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
```

and then in main_activity I make CollapsingToolbarLayout and i give its attribute values:

```
 app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
```

but when I press Run my android doesn't recognize this library and shows me this error

[image]

what's wrong with this library? how can I solve this problem?
I'd appreciate to show me a solution

Comment: Have you added "app" namespace in xml layout?

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0' try adding this line

Comment: thank you  AbhayBohra, it solves my problem

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue is due to missing "app" namespace in xml layout.

To resolve it, include `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` namespace line right after `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`